# To show that the field $\Bbb Z_p$ has no proper subfield when $p$ is a prime number.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

To show that the field $\Bbb Z_p$ has no proper subfield when $p$ is a prime number.Is the reason of having no primes due to non factorization of $p$??

Answer (score 3):

Any subfield contains $1$ which generate $\mathbf{F}_p = \mathbf{Z} / p \mathbf{Z}$'s underlying additive group, so that the subfield contains (and he's equal to) whole $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly a subfield is an additive subgroup.  But what is the only proper additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and why is it not a (sub)field?

Answer (score 1):

First look at the subrings of the field   $ Z_p$.
since  $Z_p$  is cyclic group (since prime order) so only subgroup of it ${0},Z_p$.

Since subrings should be also a subgroup with respect to addition. So the possible subrings are ${0},Z_p$.
Since for  a subfield  all elements are unit( i.e no divisor of zero)so it will be only  $Z_p$
So no proper subfiled exist .

Answer (score 0):

A subfield of a field $k$ is in particular an additive subgroup of $k$, but is easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has no proper subgroups (all non zero elements have order $p$).